# Python does not consider distutils.cfg

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I have tried everything given and the tutorials all point in the same direction about using mingw as a compiler in python instead of visual c++.

I do have visual c++ and mingw both. Problem started coming when I wanted to install using pip. It always gave `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

So as per suggestions I created a file `distutils.cfg` under the following path `c:/python27/Lib/distutils/` and added the following two lines:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

However, this file has no effect whatsoever. The same error still exists while using pip. I am trying to install numpy by the way currently although the error came earlier also.

Comment: did you find a solution for that problem?

Comment: @Oz123 Nope unfortunately except you can use the unofficial binaries from the site in the answer below but that's not the real solution I suppose.

Comment: Well, yes, it's not the best solution ... Let's hope python improves here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Difficult Solution (Building using the C/C++ compiler)**

Are you on Windows 32bit or 64bit?  Are you specifying the build when you're compiling?  For example, do the following in your shell or bash:

```
python setup.py build --compiler==mingw32
python setup.py install
```

**Easier Solution (Use pre-built binaries)**

If you don't have to compile the program, you can use the unofficial Windows binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: I had to use `--compiler=mingw32` (one equal sign) instead of `--compiler==mingw32`. I am using python 3.7

Comment: This builds an `*.egg` package. `==` is a typo and should be `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Cost me several hours to figure this out but now works like a charm.
I am on Windows 64bit and using a scientific Python distribution Enthought Canopy.

1. Ensure you have installed MinGW and the Compilers you need (C, C++, Fortran..)
2. Add `C:\MingW\bin` to your PATH in Environment variables
3. In `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\Lib\distutils`, create with notepad++ or similiar a new file `distutils.cfg`

Write and save:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler = mingw32
```

Comment: I didn't need the 2nd `[build_ext]` part, but pip doesn't (currently?) respect this file at all. The only way (AFAIK) is to use the `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32` method of creating a good old `*.egg` pcakge, and install it with `python setup.py install`. No idea why pip is not able to handle this in 2022!

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to use `virtualenv` as well?

Anyway, use [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
and a newer `setuptools`. The one bundled with virtualenv (3.6) does not support this compiler.

`pip install "setuptools>=6.0"`

Credits: http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/